# What does the '!' really do when it's added to an ex command (:wq! | :w! | :q! )?

Tags: vim

I understand that it means *force* to do something.

When doing `$ vim -R file` I enter in `read-only` mode, but this works as preventive mode only

```
-R  Readonly mode.  The 'readonly' option will be set for all the
    files being edited.  You can still edit the buffer, but will
    be prevented from accidentally overwriting a file.  If you
    forgot that you are in View mode and did make some changes,
    you can overwrite a file by adding an exclamation mark to
    the Ex command, as in ":w!".  The 'readonly' option can be
    reset with ":set noro" (see the options chapter, |options|).
    Subsequent edits will not be done in readonly mode.  Calling
    the executable "view" has the same effect as the -R argument.
    The 'updatecount' option will be set to 10000, meaning that
    the swap file will not be updated automatically very often.
```

But what I can't get yet is why it makes the instruction to skip permissions even if the file's owner is `root` user, besides it also change owner & group.

Comment: Where is the question? `vim` may do whatever it wishes inside itself, e.g. to imagine it edits a root-owned `r--` file under an ordinary user. But it’s only an application, and when about to actually do something with files, the OS kernel will check permissions anyway.

Comment: Ok but then the -w- permission must not exist for vim...

Comment: If you're interested in Vim, do checkout the sister site [vi.se].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`!` generally means what you'd expect from "force", but what it means for specific command depends on the command. In the case of `w!`, if Vim cannot write to the file for some reason, it will try to delete and create a new one with the current buffer's contents.

Consider the following example (observe the inode numbers):

```
$ touch foo
$ chmod -w foo
$ stat foo
  File: ‘foo’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 22h/34d Inode: 10396141    Links: 1
Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ muru)   Gid: ( 1000/ muru)
Access: 2015-09-10 00:24:28.259290486 +0530
Modify: 2015-09-10 00:24:28.259290486 +0530
Change: 2015-09-10 00:24:30.771263735 +0530
 Birth: -
$ vim -c 'r!date' -c 'wq!' foo
$ stat foo                    
  File: ‘foo’
  Size: 30          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 22h/34d Inode: 10396151    Links: 1
Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ muru)   Gid: ( 1000/ muru)
Access: 2015-09-10 00:24:37.727189657 +0530
Modify: 2015-09-10 00:24:37.731189614 +0530
Change: 2015-09-10 00:24:37.763189273 +0530
 Birth: -
$ cat foo
Thu Sep 10 00:24:37 IST 2015
```

That's why the owner and group changes. Permissions are preserved - [`:h write-permissions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#write-permissions):

```
                                                    write-permissions
When writing a new file the permissions are read-write.  For unix the mask is
0666 with additionally umask applied.  When writing a file that was read Vim
will preserve the permissions, but clear the s-bit.
```

If you want to make Vim refuse writes, see `:h write-readonly`:

```
                                                    write-readonly
When the 'cpoptions' option contains 'W', Vim will refuse to overwrite a
readonly file.  When 'W' is not present, ":w!" will overwrite a readonly file,
if the system allows it (the directory must be writable).
```

Note that it says "the directory must be writable" - because without a writable directory, Vim can neither delete nor create a new file.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in vim(1), `-R` ensures that the file will not be **accidentally** overwritten when the user blindly says `:w`, but doesn’t disable writing with `:w!`.

But it’s only an application, and when about to actually do something with files, the OS kernel will check permissions anyway. An experiment: I ran

```
strace vim /etc/hostname 2>vim.out
```

under a user.
Even without explicit `-R` it started in readonly, because it looked at permissions.
After changing the buffer

```
W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
```

appeared.

Now `:w` and I got

```
E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)
```

I applied the suggestion and

```
"/etc/hostname" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Predictably, in `vim.out` we see:

```
open("/etc/hostname", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score -1):

FORCE, for :w it means "SYSTEM PERMISSIONS" EVEN IF -R IS NOT SET, :q means that lose `unsaved` work